# Rbind data frames with data frame columns

Tags: r

I would like to be able to `rbind` data frames that have columns that are `data.frame`s themselves (not lists of data frames).

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1)
df$b <- data.frame(c = 2)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ b:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ c: num 2

df2 <- data.frame(a = 3)
df2$b <- data.frame(c = 4)

rbind(df, df2)

# Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
#   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
# In addition: Warning message:
# non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘1’
```

I am aware of `dplyr::bind_rows(df, df)` but I would specifically require a **base R** solution.
(I gave a quick look at how `bind_rows` does it, but as far as I can tell it defers to [C code](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/03a6898e2cfbd5788f1dcd24b15d22f78fa6ec25/R/bind.R#L150) in [`vctrs::vec_rbind`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/f4a39dcaf5058e9412ef1cbd909bcdb82a66519b/R/bind.r#L122) that is impenetrable to me.)

```
expected_output <- data.frame(a = c(1, 3))
expected_output$b <- data.frame(c = c(2, 4))
str(expected_output)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num  1 3
#  $ b:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ c: num  2 4
```

---

(Context: such data frames come from API calls parsed with `jsonlite` with simplification. While I could avoid it, I appreciate the convenience, and I am curious about this problem regardless).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use unlist()

```
rbind(df, unlist(df2))
#   a c
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4
```

Note: With this route both inputs must have the same number of cols in the same meaningful order.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df[rep(1:nrow(df), 2),]
```

However, you may have to rename the row names, if required.

Comment: Thanks. I should have made my example clearer that I don't want to `rbind` `df` with itself but with another data frame. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `bind_rows` (used the devel version of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- bind_rows(df, df2)
out
#  a c
#1 1 2
#2 3 4

str(out)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ a: num  1 3
#$ b:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ c: num  2 4
```

Comment: @JohnGarland not able to reproduce with my version

Comment: When I execute the above I get: Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames. But I am only running the latest version not the development version. I guess this means they are trying to fix this behavior??? Making unlist(df2) the second arg does not work either in this case.

Comment: @JohnGarland I noticed for several other functions the behavior changes with each version of tidyverse packages.  So, it is possible that you have an error and my version don't have